# Merge two arrays with the same key but in different depth?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

```
$arr = array('one' => array('one_1' => array('one_2' => '12')), 'two', 'three');
$arr2 = array('one_2' => 'twelve');

$merge = array_merge($arr, $arr2);

print '<pre>';
var_dump($merge);
print '</pre>';
```

gives:

```
  array(4) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["one_1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["one_2"]=>
      string(2) "12"
    }
  }
  [0]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "three"
  ["one_2"]=>
  string(6) "twelve"
}
```

I want the value of key `one_2` in the first array to be replaced with the value of the same key in the second array. So the result would be:

```
array(4) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["one_1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["one_2"]=>
      string(2) "twelve"
    }
  }
  [0]=>
  string(3) "two"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$value, $key, $replacements) {
    if (isset($replacements[$key])) {
        $value = $replacements[$key];
    }
}, $arr2);
```

Note that this uses PHP 5.3+ syntax.

Comment: Then you can simply rewrite this as normal function declaration or even using `create_function`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback and http://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive