# Recursively merge two arrays, or replace with latter based on a key

Tags: php

This should be a really easy answer and I'm probably just being thick, but I have two arrays in PHP:

```
$data1 = array(
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-1-1',
    'value' => 10,
  ),
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-2-1',
    'value' => 3,
  ),
);
$data2 = array(
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-2-1',
    'value' => 5,
  ),
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-3-2',
    'value' => 1,
  ),
);
```

And I want to result in:

```
$result = array(
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-1-1',
    'value' => 10,
  ),
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-2-1',
    'value' => 5,
  ),
  array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-3-2',
    'value' => 1,
  ),
);
```

... so that the two will be merged- but, if it finds a qid that matches another, will replace it with the latter.

I've tried a mixture of `array_merge()`, `array_merge_recursive()`, `$data1 + $data2`, `$data2 + $data1`, `array_replace()`, `array_replace_recursive()`, `array_diff()` etc, etc, but every options seems to return either two or four values rather than the three. And of course I've done my fair share of S.O hunting.

Any ideas? Would prefer something short and sweet to a massive iterating function of any sort!

Thanks in advance :)
Matt

Edit:

I've just realised that if I turn the arrays *inside* $data1 & $data2 into key-value pairs most of those merge and replace functions work, eg:

```
$data1 = array(
  'q-prof-1-1' => array(
    'qid' => 'q-prof-1-1',
    'value' => 10,
  ) // ... etc etc
);
```

... but I'd still rather not have to change the original data

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use an associative array?  That way you can just have

```
$array = array('q-prof-1-1' => 10, 'q-prof-2-1' => 3);
$array2 = array('q-prof-2-1' =>  5, 'q-prof-3-2' => 1);
```

Then just loop through $array2, push the value on if $array doesn't have a key (key_exists() if i remember right) or if it does have a key merge them how you want?

Also, but not sure, using an associative array would probably make array_merge work correctly (possibly).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I just edited my question before I saw your comment but yeah, it does work with associate arrays. However I'd prefer not to have to change the original data!

Comment: hahaha, and i guess i didn't see your edit.  This answer looks like it might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819003/merge-two-arrays-with-the-same-key-but-in-different-depth?rq=1. 

Otherwise i think your stuck writing your own recursive array_merge.  You can specify your own function for merging like in the answer above.  And then go from there.  Kinda a pain keeping original data structure.